# Laravel HTML to PDF conversion (DOMPDF)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

DOMPDF Wrapper for Laravel 5, It's a html to pdf converter for laravel 5.

I have tried to convert laravel default auth register page to PDF and the path is http://www.careertag.dev/auth/register. Code used for this purpose is given below. But I am getting font issue. Could you please help me to solve this issue?

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/screenshot', function(){
    $pdf  =  App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    //$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
    $view =  View::make('auth.register')->render();
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);
    $pdf->stream();
    //return $pdf->stream('invoice');
    return $pdf->download('profile.pdf');
});
```

**Error**

```
ErrorException in font_metrics.cls.php line 343: file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\careertag\storage\fonts/13350985545a9988387f8a573f409063.ttf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you have a **fonts** folder in **storage** directory?

Comment: @MustafaEhsan, No folder in storage directory

Comment: @MustafaEhsan, Thanks it's a folder problem. I have created fonts folder in storage and now PDF is generating.

Comment: Welcome, I have posted my solution as an answer as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create **fonts** folder inside **storage** directory and make sure **storage** is writable by web server by running follwing command. This worked for me.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```

Above (777) can be **dangerous**, therefore to achieve it in a secure way, try the below commands.

```
sudo find storage -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
sudo find storage -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: 777 is dangerous. This might be better:
`sudo find storage -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find storage -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

Copy the 'fonts' directory of your theme form the location 'project-directory/public/themes/your-theme/path-to-fonts-directory' to the location 
'project-directory/storage/fonts-directory'
This works for me when I was hanged for long time.

Comment: I have copied the fonts folder as you mentioned here. but still am getting the same error

Comment: what you give name the for the  'fonts-directory' ? it should be 'fonts'